# installing openblas on CentOS 8

Tags: r, centos8, openblas

I am trying to install R on CentOS 8 and it requires openblas-0.3.3-5.el8, but using dnf the AppStream repo only gives me openblas-0.3.3-2.el8.  Is there any way to force it to install the newer version?  Thanks in advance, I am really stuck here.

```
[bosr@rth.ad.rothschild.com@usd1sapp101 ~]$ sudo dnf install openblas
Last metadata expiration check: 0:39:47 ago on Tue 25 May 2021 06:50:01 PM CEST.
Dependencies resolved.
=================================================================================================
 Package           Architecture    Version                 Repository                       Size
=================================================================================================
Installing:
 openblas          x86_64          0.3.3-2.el8             InstallMedia-AppStream          4.3 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 4.3 M
Installed size: 31 M
Is this ok [y/N]: N
```

If I try to install R, here is the error message I get:

```
> [bosr@rth.ad.rothschild.com@usd1sapp101 ~]$ sudo dnf update
> CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                    271 MB/s | 5.4 MB     00:00
> CentOS-8 - Base                                                                         248 MB/s | 2.2 MB     00:00
> CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                                                   5.1 MB/s | 2.0 MB     00:00
> Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                  594 kB/s | 610 kB     00:01
> Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                          6.4 MB/s | 9.4 MB     00:01
> Error:
>  Problem: package R-devel-4.0.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires R-core-devel = 4.0.5-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
>   - package R-core-devel-4.0.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires openblas-devel, but none of the providers can be installed
>   - cannot install the best update candidate for package R-devel-1-1.x86_64
>   - nothing provides openblas(x86-32) = 0.3.3-5.el8 needed by openblas-devel-0.3.3-5.el8.i686
>   - nothing provides openblas-threads(x86-32) = 0.3.3-5.el8 needed by openblas-devel-0.3.3-5.el8.i686
>   - nothing provides openblas(x86-64) = 0.3.3-5.el8 needed by openblas-devel-0.3.3-5.el8.x86_64
>   - nothing provides openblas-threads(x86-64) = 0.3.3-5.el8 needed by openblas-devel-0.3.3-5.el8.x86_64
> (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
> [bosr@rth.ad.rothschild.com@usd1sapp101 ~]$
```

Answer (score 3):

The missing packages are in a repo called powertools that is disabled on Centos8 by default. You need to enable this repo then try again. On my GCP VM I ran:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
sudo yum install R
```

Comment: `dnf install 'dnf-command(config-manager)'`

Answer (score 0):

I used wget to download the newer version of openblas and openblas-threads.  I was then able to install them and then install R.  Not sure why the repo wasn't giving me the latest version, but I am good now.